# Retrofit Jackson converter doesn't recognize nested objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, retrofit, robospice

I am using `RetrofitJackson2SpiceService` to make requests in a service. Jackson is used to parse JSON responses from the API.
But I have one problem.
My `User model` has following declaration

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("surname")
    public String surname;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    public String email;
    @JsonProperty("phone")
    public String phone;
    @JsonProperty("BirthDate")
    public String birthDate;
    @JsonProperty("token_model")
    public Token token;
}
```

As you may noticed this class has Token as a member

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Token {
    @JsonProperty("token")
    public String token;
    @JsonProperty("expiration_time")
    public int expirationTime;
    @JsonProperty("scope")
    public int scope;
}
```

Server response looks like this

```
{"id":"36","email":"something@yo.com","name":"Say","surname":"hello","login":"superuser","phone":"4534333","token_model":{"token":"a220249b55eb700c27de780d040dea28","expiration_time":"1444673209","scope":"0"}}
```

Token is not being parsed, it is always null.

I have tried to convert string manually

```
 String json = "{\"id\":\"36\",\"email\":\"something@yo.com\",\"name\":\"Say\",\"surname\":\"hello\",\"login\":\"superuser\",\"phone\":\"4534333\",\"token_model\":{\"token\":\"a220249b55eb700c27de780d040dea28\",\"expiration_time\":\"1444673209\",\"scope\":\"0\"}}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = mapper.readValue(json, User.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And it works ! Token is parsed correctly without any problems.

Here I have used `readValue` method accepting String as first parameter, but in `Converter`

```
  JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(type);
  return objectMapper.readValue(body.in(), javaType);
```

Stream version of method is used.

I have tried to return Response instead of `User` object in the following way

```
  public void onRequestSuccess(Response response) {
                super.onRequestSuccess(response);
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                User user = null;
                try {
                    user = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody().in(), User.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

And it works great, like it should, token is parsed correctly.

I have no idea what can cause such problem, I have tried a lot of different combinations of annotations(custom deserializers, unwrap....), custom converters but still the same.

I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem exploring source code of `Retrofit` 
The problem is that even if my service is inherited from `RetrofitJackson2SpiceService` it doesn't use `JacksonConverter` by default.

`GsonConverter` used instead.

```
   mRestAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(getServerUrl())
            .setConverter(createConverter()) //this line   
            .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthRequestInterceptor(context))
            .setClient(new OkClient(mHttpClient))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setLog(new AndroidLog("RETROFIT"));
```

Adding converter explicitly while building rest adapter solved the problem.